# Laravel ManyToMany null id in where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I am having [this](https://laravel.io/forum/03-17-2014-many-to-many-relationship-generating-sql-with-where-clause-looking-for-null) same issue.  Exactly the same issue accept different class and table names.  Does anybody have some insight?

```
Site:
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function categoryBlocks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'blocked_category');
}

Category:
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function sites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Site::class, 'blocked_category');
}
```

The query properly generates when querying from category to site but not from site to category. (I have tried renaming the method on the site Model but it doesn't help at all.)

```
$catBlocks = $category->sites()->get();  // Query creates a category_id value in the query
$blocks = $site->categoryBlocks()->get();  // Query doesn't create a site_id value in the query


       Table: blocked_category
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,


       Table: sites
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `publisher_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',


       Table: categories
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

Comment: @alex-graeves I have tried that several times.  I have traced into the building of the query and it is finding the correct $foreignKey and $otherKey itself, however when it uses the new instance of the object and calls newQuery() it generates the query without the id of the calling object.
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:970  (I should also point out I am on Laravel 5.2)

Comment: Wouldn't let me re-edit lol, but Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:970  is where I start to see a difference in the query generation between calling from one object or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue.  The instance of the object being used to query wasn't being fully hydrated which was causing the query builder not to see the relationship properly.

I was getting the instance of the object passed into the method, but for some reason it wasn't a fully hydrated instance, so I just had to manually hydrate the Site object before running the query.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing a third argument to the categoryBlocks relationship of 'category_id':

```
public function categoryBlocks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'blocked_category', 'category_id');
}
```

Or whatever you have called the category_id within the blocked_category table. If this doesn't work please reply with your database schema.

Comment: Read Above, that is not the issue.